# Xamarin.Forms, using the Prism.Forms NavigationService

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism-6

I am trying to implement a login scenario with Xamarin Forms and Prism.

My application root page is a MasterDetail page (`HomeMasterDetailPage`); this being used to provide the side menu.

What I am trying to do is to have the `HomeMasterDetailPage` page shown with *Content* set to an instance of `LoginPage`. When the user logs in, the *Content* should change to an instance of `HomeDetailContentPage`. It should not be possible to return to the `LoginPage` using the back button.

I am using the NavigationService from Prism Forms.

My start up is like this...

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication {

    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null)
        : base(initializer) {
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized() {

        InitializeComponent();

        Uri uri = new Uri($"/{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(HomeMasterDetailPage)}/{nameof(HomeDetailContentPage)}", UriKind.Absolute);

        var settings = Container.Resolve<SettingsService>();
        if (!settings.DeviceUserID.HasValue)
            uri = new Uri($"/{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(HomeMasterDetailPage)}/{nameof(LoginPage)}", UriKind.Absolute);

        NavigationService.NavigateAsync(uri);
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes() {

        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<NavigationPage>();

        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();

        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<HomeMasterDetailPage, HomePageViewModel>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<HomeMasterContentPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<HomeDetailContentPage>();

    }

}
```

This correctly displays the `LoginPage` within the `HomeMasterDetailPage` if the user is not already logged on, and the `HomeDetailContentPage` within the same `HomeMasterDetailPage` if the user is logged on.

The problem comes when actually logging on; the following is the code within the view model for the `LoginPage`...

```
protected async Task ExecuteLoginCommand() {
    Uri uri = new Uri($"/{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(HomeMasterDetailPage)}/{nameof(HomeDetailContentPage)}", UriKind.Absolute);
    await this.navigationService.NavigateAsync(uri);
}
```

It is my understanding that by using an absolute Uri this should reset the navigation so that the new page arrangement (/NavigationPage/HomeMasterDetailPage/HomeDetailContentPage) is at the top and bottom of the stack, allowing me to then move forward from there. Instead, I am getting an unhandled exception (on Android 7.0).

What am I doing wrong?

Note: All of the examples that I see have the `MasterDetailPage` at the root with *Content* being set to `NavigationPage/ContentPage`; when I try this I do not get exceptions, however the side menu operates differently within the `MasterDetailPage` - when you tap on the "hamburger" the side menu slides in over everything (including the action/title bar) and the only way to clear it is to tap outside of the side menu that slides in whereas when I show the `MasterDetailPage` within a `NavigationPage` the side menu slides in below the action/title bar and the hamburger changes to an arrow that you can click to hide the side menu again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I've tested this exact scenario. However, if your LoginPage is the Detail of a MasterDetailPage, you may not want to perform the navigation from the LoginPage. You could, instead create a `SuccessfulLoginEvent`, which you would then publish from the LoginPage using the `IEventAggregator`, and you would subscribe to on your MasterDetailPage's ViewModel. You could then perform the navigation as `_navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/ViewA")` and it should reset the Detail such that the back button doesn't bring you to the LoginPage.

Alternatively, you can simply perform an absolute Navigation which has the effect of:
`Application.Current.MainPage = new MyPage()`.

To do to this, you could do the navigation from anywhere as:
`_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MyMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/ViewA")`

Comment: Thanks Dan, I thought I was basically doing what you suggest at the end of your answer anyway (please see my ExecuteLoginCommand code above) - it is just that I have the NavigationPage and MasterDetailPage the other way around (in order to get the correct behaviour from the MasterDetailPage as previously mentioned). Is this not the case?

Comment: Check out the [samples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/HamburgerMenu) for how to work with the MasterDetailPage. You most likely want your detail wrapped in a NavigationPage not the MasterDetailPage.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct, mainly for the comment on Apr 28 @ 19:19 which helped me finally realise that I was using the MasterDetailPage and NavigationPage incorrectly. Once I got this into my head I was able to address all other issues that I have been having with the Prism Navigation service.